# Como fazer para o node identificar o caminho a partir da raiz da requisição?

Tags: node.js, express.js

Está assim:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/node/softmon/css/style.css" type="css">
```

Se eu colocar assim:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" type="css">
```

não funciona.

Utilizo assim para visualizar a página `***http://localhost:3000***`

app.js

```
var app = require('express')(),
http = require('http').Server(app),
io = require('socket.io')(http),
dbasy = require('./node_modules/dbasy/dbasy.js'),
$ = require('cheerio'),
jsdom = require("jsdom");

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.htm');
});
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('operacoes', function(data) {
        console.log()
    }); 
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('Desconetado.');
    });
});
http.listen(1589, function(){
    console.log('Servidor iniciado.');
});
```

Como fazer para o node identificar o caminho a partir da raiz da requisição ?

Comment: nao existe view definida, eu carrego a pagina direto pelo app.get('/', function(req, res) {

 res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.htm');

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem de defenir como serve os ficheiros estáticos. Junte isto no `index.js`:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/node/softmon/'));
```

assumindo que a pasta onde tem o `index.js` tem uma subpasta `/node/`.